# replaceRoute with an object id

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I want to use the replaceRoute in an ember controller but need to pass an object id. Something along the lines of:

```
this.replaceRoute('projects.edit', 4)
```

Is that possible at all or should it be done differently? It's going to the route I tell it to but with an object id of `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that possible at all or should it be done differently?

`replaceRoute` expects to be passed the route's context, not an id. You can use the id to locate the context, for example:

```
this.replaceRoute('projects.edit', App.Project.find(4));
```

Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating how this approach using the fixture adapter

http://jsfiddle.net/mgrassotti/mhyjG/1/

Comment: Thanks again Mike. I was just passing the id, thinking the router would kick in and get me the appropriate model.